# How to use "SHFILEOPSTRUCT"

Tags: c++, windows

Hello
I try write program to create and copy some files.

If folder is not exist, when i use flag

"SH.fFlags |= FOF_SILENT;

SH.fFlags |= FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR;" at the same time, can't create folder and can't copy 
file.

Any body know why? Thanks.

```
 CString  source;
 CString  target;

 SHFILEOPSTRUCT SH = { 0 };

 SH.hwnd = NULL;
 SH.wFunc = FO_COPY;

 SH.fFlags = NULL;
 SH.fFlags |= FOF_SILENT;
 SH.fFlags |= FOF_NOCONFIRMMKDIR;
 SH.fFlags |= FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
 SH.fFlags |= FOF_WANTMAPPINGHANDLE;
 SH.fFlags |= FOF_NOERRORUI;

 source = _T("c:\\Test\\test1\\Test1.exe");
 target = _T("C:\\Backup\\Test\\");

 source += '\0';  
 target += '\0';

 SH.pTo = target;
 SH.pFrom = source;

 ::SHFileOperation( &SH );
```

Comment: tagged [windows].  If incorrect, feel free to re-edit

Comment: it means @John has edited your q to add another tag to get the right people looking at it.  This *is* C++, but people who work on Linux cannot help so the Windows tag corrects the scope.

Answer (score 0):

`CString` does not support embedded zeroes. You need to copy the string to e.g. a vector:

(I'm not sure if this is the only problem with your code, but you should fix it):

```
CString source;
std::vector<TCHAR> sourceBuffer;
sourceBuffer.resize(source.GetLength()+1); 
memcpy( &(sourceBuffer[0]), source.operator LPCTSTR(), 
    sizeof(TCHAR) * (source.GetLength()+1));  // (1)
sourceBuffer.push_back('\0');

// do the same for target / targetBuffer

SH.pTo = &(targetBuffer[0]); 
SH.pFrom = &(sourceBuffer[0]);
```

---

(1) the magic line:

- `&(sourceBuffer[0])` is a pointer to the first character of the vector buffer we just allocated, and the target of the memcpy operation
- `source.operator LPCTSTR()`  is an explicit call to the (otherwise implicit) conversion to a LPCTSTR, which gives the source of the  memcpy operation
- `source.GetLength() + 1` is the length of the string in characters, including the terminating zero
- sizeof(TCHAR) is the size of a character in bytes (usually 1 in ANSI builds, 2 in Unicode builds). memcpy expects number of bytes, so we need to multiply by that.